# Summarizing multiple files in unix

Tags: bash, unix, scope, uniq

I am trying to summarize multiple files parallely. As I display variable it contains null

```
a=`cat file1| sort | uniq | wc -l` & # file1 have 200k records

b=`cat file2|sort | uniq | wc -l` & # file1 have 240k records

sh -x process1.sh &

wait

echo a=$a

echo b=$b
```

**Output**

```
a=

b=
```

**Expected Output**

```
a=200000

b=240000
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but i think that the backround-execution via & starts a new subshell. This would mean that the variables a and b are declared in that subshells and are therefore not visible in the original shell. You can try to export them first and then start the backround-execution

Comment: I have tried to capture the process id of background process which is started via "&" this only .. no process id is captured in that case . I have attempted to export the values of a and b after "wait" which was of no use

Comment: here is the detailed output of code  .... + wait
++ cut -f14 '-d|' file1
++ sort
++ uniq
++ cut -f2 '-d|' file2
++ wc -l
++ sort
++ uniq
++ wc -l
+ b=208238
+ a=226782
+ echo a=
a=
+ echo b=
b=   .... as u can see .. value of a and b is visible during execution .. but not displayed using echo command

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a=`cat file1| sort | uniq | wc -l &`
```

instead of:

```
a=`cat file1| sort | uniq | wc -l` &
```

Also there are several minor problems:

1. useless cat.
2. using backticks instead of $(...)
3. no double quotes around variable

Refactored working version:

```
#!/bin/bash 

a=$(sort file1 | uniq | wc -l &)
b=$(sort file2 | uniq | wc -l &)
wait
echo a="$a"
echo b="$b"
```

Comment: no it didn't worked .. counting of a and b is supposed to be in parallel .. the process above makes it sequential.